# Null check operator used on a null value waiting for the network image to load

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore, networkimageview

when i sign in with a firebase user i want his profile picture to show in the home page drawer from the firestore url field, so and show in a circle avatar widget, so i wrote a function to get the url as a string and provide it to the Network image(),

```
String? stringUrl;

  Future<String?> getData() async{
    var url = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('users')
        .doc(currentUserUid)
        .get();
    setState(() {
      stringUrl= url['photourl'];
    });
    return null;
  }
```

then i provide this String url to the network image in the circle avatar widget

```
UserAccountsDrawerHeader(
              accountName: _getFieldDataToText(context, fieldName: 'name', currentUserUid: currentUserUid) ,
              accountEmail: _getFieldDataToText(context, fieldName: 'email', currentUserUid: currentUserUid) ,
              currentAccountPicture: CircleAvatar(
                backgroundImage: NetworkImage(stringUrl!),
              ),
            ),
```

but when i run my app and write my user and pw to login, just after loging in i get a red screen with this error "Null check operator used on a null value" for a second and it disappears and the app continue to work normally.

i think it's because the image is not yet reloaded so i get a null value ? i don't know whats the problem and i can't figure it out , can you help me?

i checked every async and await in the code and there is no errors.

Comment: If you print the value of the stringUrl variable via print, what will be there? Some string or null?

Comment: first i get the error then i get the printed url string

Comment: then I can advise you not to show image with null link. Or, initially assign some value to the variable. Even if it's an empty line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you put a `!` after a nullable variable you are saying "I know for certain this value is not null right now". When Flutter finds this on a value that in fact *is* `null`, it raises the error you get.

Indeed, your `stringUrl` variable will be null while the data is being loaded from the database. During that time you probably don't want to show any image in the UI, so you could for example handle it like this:

```
currentAccountPicture: stringUrl != null
  ? CircleAvatar(backgroundImage: NetworkImage(stringUrl!)),
  : CircularProgressIndicator(),
```

Answer (score 0):

Do this Instead, More effective.

```
 backgroundImage: stringUrl != null ? NetworkImage(stringUrl) : AssetImage('your/image/path'),
```

Answer (score 0):

When the application is first opened, the variable you give to the field becomes null because you cannot yet retrieve the data from the server. Later, when the data arrives, it fills the field and the error message disappears. If you don't want the red screen to appear, you can show a progress indicator in the field until the data arrives.

```
backgroundImage: stringurl ==null?CircularProgressIndicator():NetworkImage(stringUrl);
```